# Correct way to pass multiple formatters to cucumberjs

Tags: node.js, parsing, cucumberjs

I'm trying to pass in multiple formatters into my cucumberjs cli runner, I wish to, both print to console, and to generate a json file.

I'm using cucumberjs v0.8.0

Things I've tried:

```
var format = "json:out.json" //works fine out.json is generated
var format = "json:out.json, pretty" // out.json is generated, however pretty console output doesn't exist.
var format = ["json:out.json, pretty"] // fails to parse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var format = ["pretty", "json:out.json"]
```

The thing you tried, 
`var format = ["json:out.json, pretty"]` is not valid javascript, or rather it sets format to an array with one element, including comma.

Comment: After some digging I noticed my CLI version was not compatible to accept format as an Array, however I will mark this as the correct answer. My solution was to pass in the additional format to the command variable.
    var command = ["-f", "pretty"]